# Casio CTK 451 - FL studio

Tags: midi

I have the following setup:

- Windows 10
- FL studio 20
- Casio CTK-451 with MIDI (Old keyboard)

I connected my Casio to my PC and launched FL Studio. The Casio is detected as a generic MIDI by FL studio. The problem is, when I press some keys it registers (NOTE ON) and does not release and just keeps sustaining. How can I solve this, help please. Appreciate it!

Comment: you need to first find out if the issue is with the hardware or not so get yourself a midi monitoring tool and find out (independently of FL) whether a NOTE OFF signal is being sent by the CTK-451 when you release the key.

Comment: I presume the keyboard isn't doing MIDI over USB, which prompts the question: What MIDI interface are you using? Does a different keyboard work or have the same problem? Does the Casio work on a different computer or have the same problem? Try swapping pieces of the puzzle until you've isolated the faulty item (or perhaps a combination of items results in an incompatibility).